# How do we achieve "substring-match" under O(n) time?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, language-agnostic

I have an assignment that requires reading a huge file of random inputs, for example:

```
Adana 
Izmir Adnan Menderes Apt
Addis Ababa
Aden
ADIYAMAN
ALDAN
Amman Marka Intl Airport
Adak Island
Adelaide Airport
ANURADHAPURA
Kodiak Apt
DALLAS/ADDISON
Ardabil 
ANDREWS AFB
etc..
```

If I specify a search term, the program is supposed to find the lines whereby a substring occurs. For example, if the search term is "uradha", the program is supposed to show `ANURADHAPURA`. If the search term is "airport", the program is supposed to show `Amman Marka Intl Airport, Adelaide Airport`

A quote from the assignment specs: "You are to program this application taking efficiency into account as though large amounts of data and processing is involved.."

I could easily achieve this functionality using a loop but the performance would be O(n). I was thinking of using a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) but it seems to only work if the substring starts from index 0.

I was wondering what solutions are there which gives a performance better than O(n)?

Comment: Are all lines short like the ones shown?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber . Basically the requirements are vague, I'm only provided with an example file: http://qweop.com/test/airports.dat

Comment: don't you need like a quantum computer to go through a list of N items under O(n)?

Comment: @DenisTulskiy what do you mean?

Comment: @Pacerier: if you have an input string of n chars, you have to go through every one of them at least once. You can't do it faster than O(n) without a quantum computer.

Comment: There's no way to get below O(n) *for a single query*, but if you have many queries then you can get a big speedup by building a suffix tree or suffix array just once in O(n) time, then using it to solve each query in time proportional to the length *of the query*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could take a look at the [Boyer-Moore string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) or the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). They have good asymptotic performance, but I don't know of an algorithm that would not require to at least read once (almost all of) both the input and output string, and thus would have better than O(n) performance (where n is the size of the input).

Comment: For short known substrings, Rabin-Karp might also be a possibility.

Answer (score 11):

[Here's](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/fdm.html#SECTION00220) one with the O(n) as the worst case time complexity.

By the way, you should bookmark this link: http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/

Answer (score 3):

My gut says you are on the right track thinking of a trie and you may want to examine this section of the trie page on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Full_text_search) that links to [Suffix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) for some more ideas. O(n) ideas unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

It the input text has almost static content (or values are added not so often, and values are added to the end of input source), but searching is often you can try following (probably the same as trie)

1) You'll read all text (and also update then new element is added) and prepare indexes table (map of symbol to coordinate (line or line with position) where match occurs)

```
'aa' - 1, 15, 27... 
'as' - 1, 15, 17...
'ba' - 2, 3, 15...
...
```

2) First search coordinate in index table by first 2 symbols

3) Then continue search in input text by coordinates

Comment: Heys sry I'm not understanding you, wouldn't that mean that I would need to have a map for all possible inputs 'a' to 'zzzzzz' (which is too big to be realistically usable?)

Comment: This is known as an [inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index). It can be very fast, since the index tells you how to focus your search.

Comment: @Pacerier: yes the index table will be huge, even bigger then input source, but it will increase search performance.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber heys cool, however assuming I have only 3 short inputs `tiger`, `lion`, and `bear`, do you mean that I have to build a table of 33 rows (t, i, g, e, r, ti, ig, ge, er, tig, ige, ger, tige, iger, tiger, l, o, n, li, io, on, lio, ion, lion, b, e, a, be, ea, ar, bea, ear, bear) ?

Comment: Because I was wondering how scalable is this approach. Running through the test file (http://qweop.com/test/airports.dat) gives me 286318 rows..

Comment: No, that's not necessary. You can just use sequences of fixed lengths, e.g., character pairs. Searching for "tiger" is then necessary in lines where all of 'ti', 'ig', 'ge', and 'er' appear. I use something similar for assessing similarity of company names; it's an order of magnitude faster than comparing all pairs of names. The appropriate length for the index keys will depend on the data; do some testing like it were a real task.

Answer (score 1):

Boyer-Moore and several algorithms that use variants on some of its ideas can achieve "O(n/m)" (where n is the length of the haystack and m is the length of the needle) best-case performance on certain needles, but this depends on non-repetition criteria on the needle which are impossible to satisfy for arbitrarily large m (e.g. as m gets much larger than the character set size), making even the best cases something more like O(n/256) and thus O(n). Still in real-world applications where m tends to be small and needles tend not to be pathologically-periodic, BM and its cousins can perform extremely well.

Personally I recommend the "Two Way" algorithm (with the BM-like extensions used in the glibc implementation) for the fact that it has guaranteed O(n) bounds and constant working space.